# Сравнение двух одинаковых чисел не даёт true

Tags: javascript

Если даже `floor` и `yourPosition` совпадают, то *"Lift is here. Please enter!"* не выводится в консоль. В чем может быть проблема?

```
var floor = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
switch (floor) {
    case floor = 1:
        console.log("Lift is at 1st floor");
        break;
    case floor = 2:
        console.log("Lift is at 2nd floor");
        break;
    case floor = 3:
        console.log("Lift is at 3rd floor");
        break;
    case floor = 4:
        console.log("Lift is at 4th floor");
        break;
    case floor = 5:
        console.log("Lift is at 5th floor");
        break;
    case floor = 6:
        console.log("Lift is at 6th floor");
        break;
    case floor = 7:
        console.log("Lift is at 7th floor");
        break;
    case floor = 8:
        console.log("Lift is at 8th floor");
        break;
    case floor = 9:
        console.log("Lift is at 9th floor");
        break;
    case floor = 10:
        console.log("Lift is at 10th floor");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("OK");
        break;
}
var yourPosition = prompt("Which floor are you on?");
console.log("Ok, buddy! You are at " + yourPosition + " floor");
if (floor !== yourPosition) {
    console.log("Please wait a minute, lift's coming");
}
else {
    console.log("Lift is here. Please enter!");
}
```

Comment: если даже floor и yourPosition совпадают Lift is here. Please enter! не вивидиться в консоль

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь, ви мне очень помогли

Comment: Что такое `case floor = 1:`? То, есть вы делаете switch по результату присвоения floor? чтобы что?

Answer (score 8):

Ваш код работает не так как задумано, потому что Вы сравниваете между собой число и строку, используя строгое сравнение (без приведения типов).

Функция prompt возвращает строку (даже если вы напишете число туда):

```
alert(typeof(prompt('введите число'))); // Покажет string
```

Можно например привести оба аргумента сравнения к одному типу:

```
var yourPosition = +prompt("Which floor are you on?");
```

В примере выше мы используем то, что унарный плюс приводит свой аргумент к числу.

```
alert(typeof('123')); //string
alert(typeof(+'123')); //number
```

Либо использовать нестрогое сравнение:

```
if (floor != yourPosition)
```

Используя сравнение `!==` Вы говорите что типы при сравнении приводить не нужно, то есть:

```
2 != '2'; //false
2 !== '2'; //true
```

Comment: Ну и [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/274axo2L/) вдогонку. Можно ещё отметить, что `switch` в коде стоит упростить. Если этажей будет 20, то это уже будет даже не смешно.

Comment: Возможно, автору платят за кол-во строк кода =)

Comment: @SergeySnegirev, да ладно вам, явно учебное задание же)